# How do you populate an array of mongoose objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
router.get('/posts', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find({})
        var postsWithOwners = []
        posts.forEach((post) => {
            post.populate('owner').execPopulate().then((post) => {
                postsWithOwners.push(post)
            })
        })
        console.log(postsWithOwners)
        res.render('posts', { posts: postsWithOwners })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

})
```

I am trying get an array of posts each having their own full owner object so I can further use them in my templates kinda like this instead of just having their id. However, when I run my current code I get an empty array in the console.

```
{{#each posts}}
    <p>{{this.description}}</p>
    <p>{{this.owner.username}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

How can I generate an array that will have these type of objects with a full owner sub-object?

```
{
    _id: 5 f186784691422f0c9b7b8a3,
    image: Binary {
        _bsontype: 'Binary',
        sub_type: 0,
        position: 1109727,
        buffer: < Buffer 89 50 4 e 47 0 d 0 a 1 a 0 a 00 00 00 0 d 49 48 44 52 00 00 06 f4 00 00 05 24 08 06 00 00 00 04 9 c f2 35 00 00 0 c 4 b 69 43 43 50 49 43 43 20 50 72 6 f 66 69...1109677 more bytes >
    },
    description: 'lorem ipsum dolor',
    owner: {
        _id: 5 f17228489d7e01c2716f123,
        username: 'mark',
        email: 'mark@gmail.com',
        password: '$2b$08$oYwBpAwt8JcoWCXumzvbWeH7xeoWGdOOJMahG/YuiZxKeAM/dRe.O',
        __v: 0
    },
    __v: 0
}
```

My post schema

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    image: {
        type: Buffer
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
})
```

Comment: Can give some details about your schema?

Comment: you declared `postsWithOwners` but you pushed to `postsWithUsers` for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

**The Why?**

You are getting an empty array because this part of your code:

```
post.populate('owner').execPopulate()
```

is asynchronous and the `.forEach` loop won't wait for it to be completed before it moves on to the next iteration of the loop. When the forEach loop is completed, none of the `.execPopulate` method call would have been resolved, consequently, the log for `postsWithOwners` outputs an empty array because nothing has been pushed into it.

**The Fix:**

You could find a way to await each `execPopulate` call in a loop but instead of doing that, you can add a `.populate` directly on the `find` query, with that, mongoose would know to populate the owner subdocument of each Post document to be returned. Something like this:

```
router.get('/posts', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find({}).populate('owner')
        // The Post documents returned should have their owner subdocument populated
        console.log(posts);
        res.render('posts', { posts })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```

*Useful Links*:

- You can read more about async operations in javascript loops [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/)